# Why won't macOS let me write files in a directory although it is write enabled and owned by me?

Tags: command-line, time-machine, permission, filesystem

I am stumped why I can't write into a directory for which I have all permissions:

```
>ll -d .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1739 schwarz  staff  55648 Aug  1 22:33 ./

>touch xx
touch: xx: Permission denied
```

All higher-level directories have the same user permissions. The directory was copied via `cp -rp` from a TimeMachine backup.

Comment: Well, while preparing this question, I noticed the little `+` at the end of the permissions field. It means "the directory has extended security information (such as an access control list)". Now the question is: how can one view and change the ACL on MacOS?

Comment: To view ACLs, add the `-e` option to `ls` (see the man page for `ls`), and to change them use `chmod` (see *its* man page).

Comment: Thanks, @GordonDavisson, yes, `ls -e` and `chmod -N` is the solution! If you want to reap the points, feel free to formulate this as an answer, otherwise I'll go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS can manage extended security information in the form of **access control lists** (ACLs) additional to the Unix permissions.
ACLs are signaled by `ls -l` via the `+` at the end of the permissions field `drwxr-xr-x+`.

One can

- view the ACLs of a file or directory with `ls -e`, and
- remove all ACLs with `chmod -N`, or
- change individual entries in the ACLs with `chmod -a` or `+a` or `=a#`.